Battery problems with Ubuntu and Lenovo
I'm experiencing power-related issues with my laptop and am uncertain whether it's a hardware problem or an Ubuntu-specific issue. Despite recently replacing the main battery, which now shows a 65% charge level, the laptop still displays 'Not Charging' and immediately shuts down when unplugged from the power source. Additionally, the system time resets upon power loss, necessitating BIOS updates after each occurrence.
I'm considering replacing the RTC battery as a next step. Could you recommend any diagnostic procedures or tests to determine if this is indeed a charging-related hardware issue rather than an operating system problem?
Results of upower :

Results of acpi -V :


Battery-not-charging is a hardware issue, not a problem that Ubuntu can fix or mitigate. Ubuntu does not control the charging hardware. Ubuntu merely passes on information that the charging hardware reports.
